# How to move the cursor in the bash shell when echoing emojis?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, emoji

I am writing a game engine for Bash using the cursor movement feature described [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html). However, if I echo emojis or other UTF-8 characters that span more than 1 byte, the cursor position seems to get messed up.

For example, the following code is supposed to echo "13", move the cursor back 3 positions and then echo "abc" in the same place. The result should only be "abc" (ideally). Instead, I see "1abc"

```
~ $ echo -e "13\033[3Dabc"
1abc
```

A similar problem can be illustrated with the carriage feed:

```
~ $ echo -e "13\rabc"
abc3
```

Is there any good way of resolving this? I am using the Terminal app on macOS. Is there any portable way of doing this?

Note: note, not all UTF-8 chars seem to behave this way. Mostly, I have only been able to reproduce this issue with emojis:

```
~ $ while true; do read -p "Enter emoji: " x; echo $x | hexdump; echo -e "1${x}3\033[3Dabc"; done
Enter emoji: 
0000000 f0 9f 94 88 0a                                 
0000005
1abc
Enter emoji: ♞
0000000 e2 99 9e 0a                                    
0000004
abc
Enter emoji: ☞
0000000 e2 98 9e 0a                                    
0000004
abc
Enter emoji: 
0000000 f0 9f 98 8b 0a                                 
0000005
1abc
Enter emoji: 
0000000 f0 9f 83 98 0a                                 
0000005
abc
Enter emoji: 
0000000 f0 9f 80 96 0a                                 
0000005
abc
Enter emoji: 
0000000 f0 9d 95 ad 0a                                 
0000005
abc
Enter emoji: 
0000000 f0 9f 87 ba f0 9f 87 b8 0a                     
0000009
1abc
Enter emoji: ✎
0000000 e2 9c 8e 0a                                    
0000004
abc
```

Comment: While I don't readily have a solution to your question, may I give a tip? That is to check out the ncurses library. It will allow you to address any portion of the terminal.  I suppose for macOS this might be a starting point: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/ncurses.3x.html

Comment: Also, for ncurses, this might give you a brief indication of what it can do: https://rhardih.io/2010/04/using-ncurses-in-c-for-text-user-interfaces-featuring-xcode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens because a is actually rendered across two columns. On my system, the four emoji and eight digits are equally long:

```
12345678
```

It's expected that a single Wide character will require two Narrow characters to overwrite it.

Treating these emoji as wide is recommended by [Unicode TR51-16](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-16.html):

> Current practice is for emoji to have a square aspect ratio, deriving from their origin in Japanese. For interoperability, it is recommended that this practice be continued with current and future emoji. They will typically have about the same vertical placement and advance width as CJK ideographs.

Given the recommendation, I would be comfortable simply hard coding anything in the "Emoticon" Unicode block as being wide. Your other symbols that work, such as  and ☞ are not in the Emoticon block (they're in Mahjong and Miscellaneous Symbols respectively).

If you want to determine the width at runtime, you can e.g. ask Python, which helpfully reports their East Asian Width as Full/Wide even though the Unicode tables themselves label it Neutral:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; import unicodedata as u; print(u.east_asian_width(sys.argv[1]))' 
W

$ python3 -c 'import sys; import unicodedata as u; print(u.east_asian_width(sys.argv[1]))' ♞
N
```

is a bit of a special case since it's composed of two different Regional Indicator Symbols with separate code points, but Python labels each of them as Neutral so if you take that as 1 it'll still add up to 2.

Comment: One can't simply query UCD/EAW for a character and expect it to do something sane and useful in all cases because column width sometimes is ambiguous for a stand-alone character and resolves only with context. An implementation is available in http://p3rl.org/Unicode::GCString#columns

Comment: @thatotherguy - so any single UTF char will at most be 2 characters wide on the terminal and not more?

Comment: @inquisitive There are some exceptionally long ligatures like "﷽" that my system renders around 11 columns long, but I don't know if there are any specs that say that such a character should be a certain number of columns on a terminal or in a monospaced font. I tried it in a few terminals and they were all highly confused, e.g. treating it as 1 column and rendering it partially cut off at 5 columns

Comment: @thatotherguy - thanks for that example - that puts things into perspective. Yes, my terminal emulator got quite confused with that too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s="13" ; printf "$s"; sleep 2; printf "\033[$((${#s}+1))Dabc%${#s}s\n" ' '
```

I've put a delay in between the `printf`s so it's easier to see what happens.  First there's:

```
1 3
```

Two seconds later the above is overwritten with:

```
abc
```

---

How it works:  We put the unicode stuff in a string `$s`.  The `${#s}` returns the length in bytes of that string.  The length is used in `$((${#s}+1))` to calculate how many spaces back to move, then `%${#s}s` tells `printf` how many spaces it needs (plus a few more) to overwrite any leftover chars.

If "a few more" spaces is too many, counting the overwriting string gives a more precise result:

```
s="13" t="abc" 
printf "${s}"; sleep 2; printf "\033[$((${#s}+1))D$t%$((1+${#s}-${#t}))s\n" ''
```

Comment: BTW, `echo -ne ...` is better replaced with `printf '%b' "..."` (which will work reliably across more shells and runtime configurations); see Stephane's excellent post/answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: @agc - I should clarify. 4d is not going to work for all UTF-8 chars. For instance, if you try it with a pictograph, like ♞, I only need to move back 3 spaces. How should I go about determining how many chars to move back depending on the character?

Comment: @cmaster, See revised answer.

Comment: Yes, the answer is better now, but it still does not hit the mark: It gets the number of bytes of the UTF-8 encoded string, but that's a different number from the number of character columns occupied by that same string. Nevertheless, I'm going to remove my downvote now.